# How to create your own "transactions" dataset to be used for visualisation of Market Basket analysis

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am playing around with market basket visualisations. Using the following code I get a dataset that I can use for some nice visualisations.

```
library("arules")
library("arulesViz")

data("Groceries")
summary(Groceries)
```

This all works fine but the thing is that I would like to tweak the data a little.

I see that the data is defined like this:

```
class(Groceries)
[1] "transactions"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"
```

Any ideas on how I can create my own dataset like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the help file `?arules::transactions`, here's one way:

```
library(arules)

## example 1: creating transactions form a list
a_list <- list(
      c("a","b","c"),
      c("a","b"),
      c("a","b","d"),
      c("c","e"),
      c("a","b","d","e")
      )

## set transaction names
names(a_list) <- paste("Tr",c(1:5), sep = "")
a_list

## coerce into transactions
trans1 <- as(a_list, "transactions")
trans1
# transactions in sparse format with
#  5 transactions (rows) and
#  5 items (columns)
```